# what does the puple striped area mean when selecting a dom-element in chrome developer tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

When trying to solve a huge white space at the bottom of an application. I noticed this purple striped area for the first time in chrome developer tools. At this point i didn't find any documentation on it, so I have no clue what it means. (see screenshot)

[screenshot of the chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhRM.png)